# line following robot using dsp and image processing

Tags: c++, c

I am taking part in a line following robot competition where we use a camera in order to follow line.

My algorithm is:

```
mean filter
--> Gaussian filter
--> find centroid
--> kalman filter
--> do pid for steering
--> do pid for speed of back motor
```

and the robot performs 98% perfectly.

My issue is that after all this filtering, sometimes I see some huge error in the reading of the camera when the robot moves, which cause small oscillation of the robot.

How can I eliminate this error?
(this small error in high speed is a big issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably setting up the buffers before image processing can work.
Assume of three buffers (image pages saved continuously from camera)... page1, page2, page3.
Use page1 to process the image... Then get an average image by comparing both page2 and page3, and put this resulting image on page1... then repeated the image processing from page1 again... and so on.

Comment: tx for reply,do I need to put some weight for pages.for example (page1*3+page*2+page3*1)/6 or I have to (page1+page2+page3)/3.

Comment: in the case yes.can you sugest me some values.and do I have to do this after my filter gussian filtering or I have to do this to raw images.

Comment: in the case yes.can you suggest me some values.and do I have to do this after my filter Gaussian filtering or I have to do this to raw images.my second concern is that when I do Gaussian filtering my centroid is highlighted but if the image has a lots of noise(my camera is almost blind sometimes) centroid which is highlighted doesn't have any meaning again,hence when you do averaging although you improve the image but again image doesn't have any meaning.